# Jacobian of composition of 2 functions.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Here is a question in my assignment which states that given:
$$f(x,y)=(2x+y,3x+2y)~~~\text{and}~~~g(u,v)=(2u-v,3u+v)$$  ,

Find the jacobian matrix of $gof$ .
I can't understand how to go with this....Any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ F = g(f(x,y)) = (2(2x + y) - 3x - 2y, 3(2x + y) + 3x + 2y) = (x, 9x + 5y) $$

The jacobian would then be

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 9 & 5 \end{bmatrix} .$$

Because $F_1 = x$ and $F_2 = 9x + 5y$.